# What need to run rdlc report in customer's PC?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, rdlc

I have developed a WPF application that uses rdlc report (Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForm) in VS2012. Applications running on my computer very well. But when I run the application in customer's PC (does not has development environment like visual studio) then the report does not show (I have installed .NET Framework on that PC).

What need to be installed on that PC to show rdlc report?
pzl help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install report viewer on client PC, so it can show rdlc correctly.

Below is the link
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35747

Comment: Thanks @silverknightone
Affter intall both MICROSOFT REPORT VIEWER 2012 RUNTIME and Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Feature Pack on client PC, rdlc work correctly.